# Moved my locally hosted website to a web host and now the php login script does not function

Tags: php

first post here.  I recently completed an into to website coding class and I decided to switch over from an xampp locally hosted website to a legit hosted website.  When I made the change, the login/create an account page do not function properly.  The create an account page does not create a new file with the hashed password and the login page doesn't start the session.  Any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>
 <h1>Welcome to Brendan's Final Project</h1>
 <h1>Please Login</h1>
 <h1>You can create an account by using the link below</h1>
  <form id="loginForm" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></input><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></input><br>
  <a href="createnewaccount.php">Create Account Page</a>
  </form>
  </center>
  <script>
  </script>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 $word = $_POST["username"];
 $word2 = $_POST["password"];
 session_start();
 $mode = $_POST["submit"];
 if($mode == "Logout"){
  unset($_SESSION["username"]);
  unset($_SESSION["password"]);
 }
 else{
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
 }
 if(file_exists("Users/".$word.".php")){
  $hash = file_get_contents("Users/".$word.".php");
  if(!empty($password) && password_verify($password, $hash)){
   $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
   $_SESSION["password"] = $hash;
   header("Location: http://digipen.byethost10.com/members.php");
  }
  else{
   echo "Error: Password is incorrect";
  }
 }
 else{
  echo "Error: No user created with that username";
 }
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Create New Account</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>
  <h1>Please create an account below</h1>
  <h1>The passwords are hashed and stored securely</h1>
  <form id="loginForm" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></input><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input><br>
  <input type="password" name="repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password"></input><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input><br>
  <a href="index.php">Back to Login Page</a><br>
  </form>
  </center>
  <script>
  </script>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  if($_POST["submit"] == "Submit"){
  $word = $_POST["username"];
  $word2 = $_POST["password"];
  $word3 = $_POST["repeat"];
   if(!file_exists("Users/".$word.".php") && $word2 == $word3){ // if can make new user with that username
    file_put_contents("Users/".$word.".php", password_hash($word2, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    echo "User Created";
   }
   else if($word2 != $word3){ 
    echo "Passwords Do Not Match";
   }
   else if(file_exists("Users/".$word.".php") == true){ 
    echo "Username Taken";
   }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: Do you have write permission for the file you're trying to create?

Comment: I believe that this is my problem, and now I'm looking to make the create an account files stored in the sql database